# SQL query to LINQ conversion with nested select statements

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert the following query to LINQ:

```
 SELECT LV.* FROM LowerVehicles LV
 INNER JOIN (Select VSerial,MAX(updatedOn) MaxUpdatedOn from LowerVehicles group by vserial) LVG
 ON LV.VSerial = LVG.VSerial AND LV.updatedOn = LVG.MaxUpdatedOn
```

Comment: Write first the query for nested `select`, save it in variable after write second `select` using that variable.

Comment: You should show us your efforts first. If at any point you are struck, we are here to help you.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. Show us what you've tried and any errors you're seeing and we'd be happy to lend a hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing your entities classes, here is an approximation. You can use query syntax or fluent syntax. Sometimes one is preferable over the other, and in the case of joins and grouping I prefer to use query syntax.

**QUERY SYNTAX**

```
var query = from LV in LowerVehicles
        join LVG in (
        from r in LowerVehicles
        group r by r.vserial into g
        select new {VSerial = g.Key, MaxUpdatedOn = g.Max(t => t.updatedOn)})
        on LV.VSerial equals LVG.Vserial
        and LV.updatedOn equals LVG.MaxUpdatedOn
        select LV;
```

**FLUENT SYNTAX**

```
var lvg = LowerVehicles.GroupBy(t => t.vserial)
                       .Select(g => new { 
                                           VSerial = g.Key, 
                                           MaxUpdatedOn = g.Max(t => t.updatedOn) 
                                        });

var query = LowerVehicles.Join( 
                                lvg, 
                                a => new { a.VSerial, a.updatedOn }, 
                                b => new { b.VSerial, b.MaxUpdatedOn }, 
                                (a, b) => new { LV = a, LVG = b}
                              )
                         .Select(t=> t.LV);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Something.LowerVehicles
.Join(something.LowerVehicles.Select(y => new { y.VSerial, updatedOn = y.updatedOn.Max() }).GroupBy(z => z.VSerial), 
 x => new { x.VSerial, x.updatedOn }, 
 lvg => new { lvg.VSerial, lvg.updatedOn }, 
 (x, y) => x)
```